# What's wrong with FindFormula after I set the value of x from 100 to 1000?

Tags: machine-learning

**The first code here.**

```
x = 100;
list4 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}]; list5 = Table[3 i, {i, 3, x}];
Transpose[{list4, list5}] // FindFormula
```

> Output:

```
3. #1^0.5 &
```

**The second one**

```
x = 1000;
list4 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}]; list5 = Table[3 i, {i, 3, x}];
Transpose[{list4, list5}] // FindFormula
```

> Output:

```
\!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"\[Piecewise]", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "215.59113232341036`"}], "-", 
RowBox[{"462.8447599959154`", " ", 
RowBox[{"Log", "[", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1.`"}], "+", "#1"}], "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"510.22846254395745`", " ", 
RowBox[{"Log", "[", "#1", "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0076258318162933944`", " ", "#1"}]}], 
RowBox[{"9.`", "<=", "#1", "<", "63221.253155283164`"}]},
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "3396.8684645398685`"}], "+", 
RowBox[{"365.162688790241`", " ", 
RowBox[{"Log", "[", "#1", "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0014401159532839128`", " ", "#1"}]}], 
RowBox[{"63221.253155283164`", "<=", "#1", "<", "705500.890275878`"}]},
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "7319.177400203924`"}], "+", 
RowBox[{"687.8323472075917`", " ", 
RowBox[{"Log", "[", "#1", "]"}]}], "+", 
RowBox[{"0.0008165452390911563`", " ", "#1"}]}], 
RowBox[{"705500.890275878`", "<=", "#1", "<", "1.`*^6"}]},
{"0", 
TagBox["True",
"PiecewiseDefault",
AutoDelete->True]}
},
AllowedDimensions->{2, Automatic},
Editable->True,
GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Left}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1.}}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.84]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}},
Selectable->True]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Left}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{1.}}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.35]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}}],
"Piecewise",
DeleteWithContents->True,
Editable->False,
SelectWithContents->True,
Selectable->False,
StripWrapperBoxes->True]\)
```

*Is there a means for me find the exact Formula after I set x to 1000?*

Comment: For exact, use `FindSequenceFunction[Transpose[{list4, list5}]]`...

Comment: How can I achieve that with ```FindFormula```? @ciao

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

[`FindFormula`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFormula.html) uses a randomized approach with the allowed [`TargetFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions.html) `{Plus, Times, Power, Sin, Cos, Tan, Cot, Log, Sqrt, Csc, Sec, Abs, Exp}` within the [`TimeConstraint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstraint.html). Using a large number of data points uses the available time dealing with all of the data. Generally, it is better to limit the amount of data used. Alternatively, restrict the set of `TargetFunctions` and increase the `TimeConstraint`. Because the approach is randomized, you generally need to specify the [`RandomSeeding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSeeding.html) option to get reproducible results.

```
x = 1000;
list4 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}]; list5 = Table[3 i, {i, 3, x}];

f1 = With[{n = 10},
   Transpose[{list4[[1 ;; n]], list5[[1 ;; n]]}] // 
    FindFormula[#, RandomSeeding -> 1234] &] // Rationalize

(* 3 Sqrt[#1] & *)

f2 = Transpose[{list4, list5}] //
   FindFormula[#,
     TargetFunctions -> {Times, Power},
     TimeConstraint -> 15,
     RandomSeeding -> 1234] & //
  Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: What's the meaning of "1234"? why do you choose ```RandomSeeding``` ->1234?  Does that mean  a specific formula to solve this?  How about set the value of ```RandomSeeding``` to 123? Is that gonna be okay?

Comment: As stated in the documentation for `RandomSeeding`, "use an explicit integer or string as a seed". It doesn't matter what you use since the intent is just to enable starting at the same point and being able to reproduce the results.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work properly

```
x = 100;
list4 = Table[i^2, {i, 3, x}]; list5 = Table[3 i, {i, 3, x}];
data = Transpose[{list4, list5}];
fy = FindFormula[data, y]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[fy, {y, 0, 10000}]]
```